# ExtJS 4.2 - Grid column header text should be visible entirely on the first load

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have a simple ExtJS grid with 5 columns in it. I need the columns to resize to based on header text size on first load. i.e., all the column headers should be visible.

I already tried

```
grid.columns[3].autoSize();
grid.columns[4].autoSize();
```

but it resizes according to column content width and not the header text itself.
Also, fixed widths and flex are not an option.

The problem is, that the header text is dynamic and it's important that header text is entirely visible each time the grid is loaded and at the same time, the width of column should not exceed header text size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its work for me by providing flex property.

```
columns : [{header : 'Name',dataIndex : 'name', flex : 1},{header : 'First    Name',dataIndex : 'firstName', flex : 1}]
```

Comment: Flex is also not an option. This is because I am using it for other columns.

Comment: What do you exactly want

Comment: I have edited the question to clearly state the problem, thank you for pointing out. :) Any ideas?